# Setting connection and thread sizes in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord, heroku, puma

Have a Heroku app running on Puma, and this morning it threw an error several times after starting up -

```
PG::DuplicatePstatement: ERROR: prepared statement "a10" already exists
```

This occured in ActiveRecord's `postgresql_adapter`, so I figured [from this writeup](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/22/show-some-love-for-prepared-statements-in-rails-3-1) it was a problem with preloaded statements and how ActiveRecord caches queries. Essentially a prepared statement (`a10`) already existed and another request tried to create the same thing.

Digging deeper, my best guess is that it is the result of a forked process on startup (e.g. Puma workers) that incorrectly share the same connection (?) and try to write over each other.

It looks like the app has **3 workers**, with **5 threads** each, and a db **pool size of 2**.

1. What does this mean, exactly? Does it mean that there are 3 worker processes that can spawn up to 5 threads and open (max) 2 db connections among all of them?
2. If the above is true, isn't it bad that each worker has 5 threads competing for 2 connections? I may be misunderstanding the actual definition of the terms *worker*, *process*, and *thread*
3. Any insight on what might have caused the error at the top? Am I looking in the right place, or does the process connection setup have little to do with anything here?

Thanks in advance!

#### config/puma.rb

```
workers 2
threads_count = 5
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup DefaultRackup
port ENV["PORT"] || 3000
environment ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

#### config/database.yml

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_db
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  min_messages: warning
  pool: 2
  timeout: 5000

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db_test
```